# "то" необходимо когда?

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

Ответ справочной службы русского языка на вопрос:

> Скажите, допустимо ли так строить предложения:
>
> ***в случае если*** мы придём поздно, ***то*** дверь будет открыта.
>   ***поскольку*** мы пришли поздно, ***то*** дверь была закрыта.
>
> Или *то* нужно непременно убрать?

Ответ такой:

> "*То*" в этих предложениях обязательно нужно убрать.

Правильный ли этот ответ?

Ведь у Пушкина, например,

> В случае если присяжные закатают меня, то я обращусь к своему старому другу…

У Катаева:

> В случае, если за вами кто-нибудь и прилипнет, то пускай видит, куда вы пошли.

Выходит, есть два союза:

в случае(,) если
и
в случае(,) если... то

Когда "*то*" необходимо, а когда - нет?

Answer (score 2):

(1) В СЛУЧАЕ ЕСЛИ мы придём поздно, ТО дверь будет (уже заранее) открыта.

(2) ПОСКОЛЬКУ мы пришли поздно, ТО дверь была (уже) закрыта.

В скобках указана НЕОБХОДИМАЯ дополнительная лексика, помогающая понять смысл предложения.

Пояснение

1) Предложение (1)  является придаточным с особым потенциальным условием (это условие может осуществиться или уже осуществилось, но говорящий об этом не знает), двойной сложный союз В СЛУЧАЕ ЕСЛИ...ТО.

Предложный оборот "в случае" выполняет роль коррелята (соотносительного слова), но он факультативен (необязателен), поэтому на общую структуру двойного союза не влияет (В СЛУЧАЕ ЕСЛИ...ТО,  ЕСЛИ...ТО).

2) В предложении (2) придаточное предложение, находясь в препозиции, имеет причинно-следственное значение, двойной союз ПОСКОЛЬКУ...ТО.

3) Таким образом, двойные союзы в приведенных примерах возможны, но в предложениях допущена другая  неточность: в них отсутствует дополнительная лексика, помогающая понять смысл предложения и поэтому относящаяся к необходимым структурным элементам.

В то же время эта лексика может отсутствовать, если выражаемый ею смысл можно понять из контекста. Если же предложения рассматриваются отдельно, то они кажутся грамматически неверными, хотя в них и нет грамматических ошибок.

4) По поводу двойных союзов

А для чего нам вообще нужны двойные союзы КОГДА...ТО, ЕСЛИ...ТО? (Такие союзы легко заменяются на КОГДА и ЕСЛИ, то есть элемент ТО является факультативным). Двойные союзы вносят дополнительную семантику в отношения между главной и придаточной частью в СПП, добавляя к значению времени, причины  или условия значение следствия.